# Problema al crear un JSON desde Servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

Buenas, quiero pasar desde un `Servlet` a un `JavaScript` un `Json` con los siguientes datos. Un repartidor tiene varios pedidos asignados, entonces yo quiero pasar el id y la posición del repartidor, junto al id y dirección de los pedidos que tiene asignado.

**MiServlet.java**

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Consulta cons, cons1;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray  resultado = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject repartidor;
    JSONArray pedidos = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject pedido;

    int idRep, idPed;
    double repLat, repLng;
    String pedDireccion;

    try {
        repartidor = new JSONObject();
        pedido = new JSONObject();
        cons = new Consulta("*", "repartos r, pedidos p");
        cons1 = new Consulta("*", "usuarios");

        ResultSet rs1 = cons1.recuperar("estado <> 'INACTIVO'");
        while (rs1.next()){
            idRep = rs1.getInt("id");
            repLat = rs1.getDouble("posLat");
            repLng = rs1.getDouble("posLng");

            repartidor.put("idRepartidor", idRep);
            repartidor.put("latRepartidor", repLat);
            repartidor.put("lngRepartidor", repLng);

            ResultSet rs = cons.recuperar("idRepartidor = " + idRep + " and r.idPedido = p.id and p.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM pedidos WHERE estado = 'ENTREGADO' OR estado = 'NO ENTREGADO' OR estado = 'CANCELADO')");
            while (rs.next()){
                idPed = rs.getInt("idPedido");
                pedDireccion = rs.getString("direccion");

                pedido.put("idPedido", idPed);
                pedido.put("direccionPedido", pedDireccion);

                pedidos.put(pedido);
            }
            repartidor.put("Pedidos", pedidos);
            resultado.put(repartidor);
        }
        json.put("Resultado", resultado);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
    }        
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Al hacer un `console.log()` desde el `JavaScript`, me retorna esto:

```
Object
    Resultado: Array[3]
        0: Object
            Pedidos: Array[3] // todos los datos de los pedios
            idRepartidor: 15
            latRepartidor: 0
            lngRepartidor: 0
        1: Object
            Pedidos: Array[3] // todos los datos de los pedios
            idRepartidor: 15
            latRepartidor: 0
            lngRepartidor: 0
        2: Object
            Pedidos: Array[3] // todos los datos de los pedios
            idRepartidor: 15
            latRepartidor: 0
            lngRepartidor: 0
```

Me trae el mismo repartidor. En la bd tengo 3 repartidores con estado '*ACTIVO*' y con pedidos asignados pero no me los trae.

---

ACTUALIZACIÓN

En la bd en la tabla repartos tengo estos registros:

```
idRepartidor  -  idPedido
    11              31
    11              32
    12              33
```

Me trae para el repartidor 11 los tres pedidos (31,32,33) y para el resto de repartidores también.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que hacer los new() de los objetos JSONObject dentro de los bucles de las consultas, de lo contrario estás escribiendo siempre sobre las mismas instancias de objeto java.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Consulta cons, cons1;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray  resultado = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject repartidor;
    JSONArray pedidos = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject pedido;

    int idRep, idPed;
    double repLat, repLng;
    String pedDireccion;

    try {
        cons = new Consulta("*", "repartos r, pedidos p");
        cons1 = new Consulta("*", "usuarios");

        ResultSet rs1 = cons1.recuperar("estado <> 'INACTIVO'");
        while (rs1.next()){
            repartidor = new JSONObject();
            idRep = rs1.getInt("id");
            repLat = rs1.getDouble("posLat");
            repLng = rs1.getDouble("posLng");

            repartidor.put("idRepartidor", idRep);
            repartidor.put("latRepartidor", repLat);
            repartidor.put("lngRepartidor", repLng);
            pedidos = new JSONArray();

            ResultSet rs = cons.recuperar("idRepartidor = " + idRep + " and r.idPedido = p.id and p.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM pedidos WHERE estado = 'ENTREGADO' OR estado = 'NO ENTREGADO' OR estado = 'CANCELADO')");
            while (rs.next()){

                pedido = new JSONObject();
                idPed = rs.getInt("idPedido");
                pedDireccion = rs.getString("direccion");

                pedido.put("idPedido", idPed);
                pedido.put("direccionPedido", pedDireccion);

                pedidos.put(pedido);
            }
            repartidor.put("Pedidos", pedidos);
            resultado.put(repartidor);
        }
        json.put("Resultado", resultado);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
    }        
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias! pero actualicé la pregunta porque me salió otro problema, si te das cuenta cual puede ser el error. Gracias por la solución del otro problema.

Comment: Haz new de pedidos para cada uno de los repartidores.

Comment: Ahí tienes, editado.